# Different colors for links when displayed on screen vs. in print?

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

Is it possible to have different colors for on screen and hardcopy display of hyperref links in the same file?

In my thesis, I like the functionality of linking reference numbers to the reference entry in the bibliography and I like having the pubmed links in the bibliography work. Having the links be blue or red helps indicate that they are clickable. But the links don't have any use in a printed copy. As is they come out a shade of grey when printed.

I know I can generate two different PDFs with different color settings, but I was wondering if there is some way to make the links come out solid black when printed but simultaneously display in color on the screen from the same PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the thread "[Colored hyperref links](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/f5e2e24527de7e3d/c6bc129624405bf3?lnk=gst&q=hyperlink+colour+print)" on comp.text.tex.

Comment: That works! Thanks! (I had to update my hyperref to a version that included the ocgcolorlinks option. evince still prints the links in color, but Acrobat works as desired)

Thanks again!

Comment: the following works for me: `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=magenta,anchorcolor=magenta,citecolor=magenta,filecolor=magenta,menucolor=black,runcolor=magenta,urlcolor=magenta]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}`